# Set up constraints for HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, horizontalscrollview

I have a layout like the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:maxHeight="50dp"
    tools:context=".navigation.NavigationFragment">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_scroll_container"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent">

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button1XXX"
                    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"/>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button2"
                    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"/>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button3"
                    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"/>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button4"
                    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"/>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button5"
                    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/search_layout"
        android:layout_width="58dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/horizontal_scroll_container"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

What I want to achieve is to have the scroll view scrolling under the pinkish square in order to reveal the latest button (`Button 5` in this case).

### [image]

Can you help me on find what I'm doing wrong? I've tried to put the constraints both in `horizontal_scroll_container` and in `HorizontalScrollView` but nothing seems to work.

P.S. I'm not an Android dev so be patient  with me ;)

Comment: you want to put a vertical scroll view inside that pink square?

Comment: @Tabish no, the scroll view and the pink square are siblings

Comment: oh okay so in my opinion you should not add another layout outside framelayout you should add it below `HorizontalScrollView` and add `android:clickable="true"` in both layouts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is constrain your `FrameLayout` on the right to the left of the `search_layout` so they don't overlap. This way the last `Button` will be fully visible.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/horizontal_scroll_container"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/search_layout">
```

The `width` was changed to `0dp` (`MATCH_CONSTRAINT`) so the container of the `ScrollView` takes all available horizontal space.

In fact, the `FrameLayout` container is not needed at all. `HorizontallScrollView` is a subclass of `FrameLayout` so there is no need to nest them. The same result can be achieved by having the `HorizontalScrollView` as a direct child of `ConstraintLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:maxHeight="50dp"
    tools:context=".navigation.NavigationFragment">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_scroll"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/search_layout">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button1"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button2"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button3"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button4"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button5"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/search_layout"
        android:layout_width="58dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/horizontal_scroll"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```